# Using linear map $\partial:\Bbb R[E]\rightarrow\Bbb R[V]$ to prove that $\#V-\#W=1$ for a tree

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

> For a directed graph $(V,E),$ there is a linear map $\partial:\Bbb R[E]\rightarrow\Bbb R[V]$ defined by $\partial (a,b)=b-a.$
>   Prove that the following are equivalent for a directed graph $(V, E).$
>   $(1)\; \#V−\#E= 1.\\(2)\; (V, E) \text{ is a tree, i.e. }  (V\text{, } E) \text{ has no non-trivial cycles and is connected.}$

To prove this, I need to use the fact that  $(V\text{, }E)\text{ has no cycles iff ker } \partial= 0.$

My general idea is that if $(V,E)$ has no non-trivial cycles, then $\partial$ is injective. This implies that $\#E=\text{dim im }\partial.$ Furthermore, connectedness $\implies \#V-\text{dim im }\partial=1\implies \#V-\#E=1$

Comment: Looks like a good plan.  To prove your final assertion, it would suffice to show that there exists $v_0 \in V$ such that for all $v \in V$, there exists $w \in \mathbb{R}[E]$ such that $v = v_0 + \partial(w)$.  But $G$ is connected, so there is a path from $v_0$ to $v$ ...